# Inheritance - Sharing info between child and parent controllers

Tags: symfony

**Context**

I have a custom `Event` Entity which has several child Entities: `Problem` and `Maintenance` (and few others but those two should be enough to describe the problem) entity classes inherit from `Event` entity class.

The `addAction()`, `seeAction()` and `modifyAction()` of `ProblemController` and `MaintenanceController` are (obviously) very similar but with some differences.

I want to have a button to display the `see` view of an `Event`, no matter if it is a `Problem` or a `Maintenance`. Same for modify.

For the add action it is a bit different: the user has to say (by clicking on child-specific button) what kind of child he want to add.

**How I handle this so far**

In my `seeAction()` and `modifyAction()`, I just forward the "call" depending on the type of the child:

```
public function seeAction(Event $event)
{
    if($event instanceof \Acme\EventBundle\Entity\Problem){
        return $this->forward('AcmeEventBundle:Problem:see', array('event_id' => $event->getId()));
    }
    elseif($event instanceof \Acme\EventBundle\Entity\Maintenance){
        return $this->forward('AcmeEventBundle:Maintenance:see', array('maintenance_id' => $event->getId()));
    }
}
```

I have no `Event::addAction()` but I have a `Event::addCommon()` which gathers the common parts of the addAction of Problem and Maintenance. Then I call this `Event::addCommon()` with Controller inheritance.

```
class ProblemController extends EventController
{      
  public function addAction(MeasurementSite $measurementSite)
  {
    $problem = new Problem();
    $problem->setMeasurementSite($measurementSite);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProblemType($measurementSite), $problem);

    $response = parent::addCommon($problem, $form);
    return $response;
  }
```

**Problem**

All this looks pretty ugly to me. If I want to share common things between `Problem::seeAction()` and `Maintenance::seeAction()`, I will have to call an `Event` function, but `Event` already forwarded something!! Information jumps from Parent to Child and vice versa...

I would like to know what is the proper way to manage this problem?

I looked a bit at setting Controller as a service, using PHP Traits, Routing inheritance but I couldn't extract anything clear and clean from this research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how you might end up chasing your tail on this sort of problem.

Instead of multiple controllers, consider have one EventController for all the routes along with individual ProblemHelper and MaintainenceHelper objects. The helper objects would have your add/see/modify methods and could extend a CommonHelper class.

Your controller would check the entity type, instantiate the helper and pass control over to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like a good idea. I'm trying to implement it, but there are functions which I always used in Controller and now I have to use then outside (e.g. `$form = $this->createForm(new ProblemType($measurementSite), $problem);` or `$request = $this->get('request');`. The `$this->` obviously creates problems because it points on a non-object. I didn't managed to figure what I should use/include/extend/modify to make this work outside a controller. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sure.  Have your helpers extend from the Symfony controller class and then have your controller inject the container.  Think of them as sub controllers if it helps.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with services so I struggled a bit but I finally managed to get the thing work. It's not fully finished yet but it already looks much nicer than before! Thanks for the help.